# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/options/CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser$OptionsProvider throwing in maven serenity-cucumber project

Tags: maven, cucumber, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I'm trying to get the base for a serenity-cucumber5 project going by tweaking a starter project I found on GitHub. I've updated the pom.xml file with the latest version numbers so it won't error out anymore, but when I run it through a maven (mvn clean verify), I get a build success, but no tests actually run and I get the following error and stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/ParserException
    at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.loadFromFeatureFile (FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:609)
    at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.readRequirementsFromStoryOrFeatureFile (FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:564)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept (ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining (Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential (ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential (ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate (AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach (ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.capabilitiesAndStoriesIn (FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:196)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept (ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining (HashMap.java:1694)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential (ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate (AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect (ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.getRequirements (FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:178)
    at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.readChildrenFrom (FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:726)
    at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.requirementFromDirectoryName (FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:635)
    at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.readRequirementFrom (FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:557)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept (ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining (Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential (ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential (ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate (AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach (ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.capabilitiesAndStoriesIn (FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:192)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept (ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining (HashMap.java:1694)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential (ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate (AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect (ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.getRequirements (FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:178)
    at net.thucydides.core.requirements.RequirementsProvided.by (RequirementsProvided.java:15)
    at net.thucydides.core.requirements.reports.MultipleSourceRequirmentsOutcomeFactory.buildRequirementsOutcomesFrom (MultipleSourceRequirmentsOutcomeFactory.java:57)
    at net.thucydides.core.reports.html.HtmlAggregateStoryReporter.generateReportsForTestResultsIn (HtmlAggregateStoryReporter.java:154)
    at net.thucydides.core.reports.html.HtmlAggregateStoryReporter.generateReportsForTestResultsFrom (HtmlAggregateStoryReporter.java:136)
    at net.serenitybdd.maven.plugins.SerenityAggregatorMojo.generateHtmlStoryReports (SerenityAggregatorMojo.java:250)
    at net.serenitybdd.maven.plugins.SerenityAggregatorMojo.execute (SerenityAggregatorMojo.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gherkin.ParserException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
    at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.loadFromFeatureFile (FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:609)
    at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.readRequirementsFromStoryOrFeatureFile (FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:564)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept (ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining (Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential (ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential (ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate (AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach (ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.capabilitiesAndStoriesIn (FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:196)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept (ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining (HashMap.java:1694)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential (ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate (AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect (ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.getRequirements (FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:178)
    at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.readChildrenFrom (FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:726)
    at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.requirementFromDirectoryName (FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:635)
    at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.readRequirementFrom (FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:557)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept (ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining (Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential (ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential (ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate (AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach (ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.capabilitiesAndStoriesIn (FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:192)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept (ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining (HashMap.java:1694)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential (ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate (AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect (ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.getRequirements (FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:178)
    at net.thucydides.core.requirements.RequirementsProvided.by (RequirementsProvided.java:15)
    at net.thucydides.core.requirements.reports.MultipleSourceRequirmentsOutcomeFactory.buildRequirementsOutcomesFrom (MultipleSourceRequirmentsOutcomeFactory.java:57)
    at net.thucydides.core.reports.html.HtmlAggregateStoryReporter.generateReportsForTestResultsIn (HtmlAggregateStoryReporter.java:154)
    at net.thucydides.core.reports.html.HtmlAggregateStoryReporter.generateReportsForTestResultsFrom (HtmlAggregateStoryReporter.java:136)
    at net.serenitybdd.maven.plugins.SerenityAggregatorMojo.generateHtmlStoryReports (SerenityAggregatorMojo.java:250)
    at net.serenitybdd.maven.plugins.SerenityAggregatorMojo.execute (SerenityAggregatorMojo.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>serenity-cucumber5-starter</name>
    <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
    <artifactId>serenity-cucumber5</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description>Serenity Cucumber integration</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <bintray.repo>serenity/maven</bintray.repo>
        <bintray.package>serenity-cucumber5</bintray.package>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <serenity.version>2.1.2</serenity.version>
        <cucumber.version>6.10.3</cucumber.version>
        <maven.core.version>3.5.0</maven.core.version>
        <maven.repoorting.version>3.0</maven.repoorting.version>
        <maven.plugin.version>3.5</maven.plugin.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
        <mokito.version>1.10.19</mokito.version>
        <assertj.version>3.6.2</assertj.version>
    </properties>
    <url>https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber5</url>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/license/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>johnsmart</id>
            <name>John Ferguson Smart</name>
            <email>john.smart@wakaleo.com</email>
        </developer>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber5.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber5.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber5</url>
        <tag>serenity-cucumber4-2.1.0</tag>
    </scm>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.31</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                    <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <parallel>classes</parallel>
                    <threadCount>5</threadCount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-cucumber5</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-screenplay</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-screenplay-webdriver</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatable-matchers</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.14</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
<!--            <scope>compile</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.21</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>bintray-serenity-maven</id>
            <name>serenity-cucumber5</name>
            <url>https://api.bintray.com/maven/${bintray.repo}/${bintray.package}/;publish=1</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

I know I've got to be missing something from my pom or elsewhere, but haven't been able to figure out what. Any help or insight would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your dependencies are inconsistent. You can use `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true` to determine what exactly the problem is. Though I suspect it comes from mixing incompatible versions of Cucumber and Serenity.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I've been using mvn dependency: tree, but didn't know about the verbose bit. That has helped me clear out some of the extra dependencies I didn't realize were included under other things. At least I'm getting some different errors now, haha.